# An error occured when trying to view folder files in brackets extension - extract for brackets

Tags: adobe-brackets, creative-cloud

I have just installed brackets and plugin extract for brackets. I have already registered in creative cloud assets and logged in but I have this kind of error. Can anyone help me?

[image: See screenshot here]

Answer (score 0):

Try to install 1.7 version instead of 1.8. All files and extensions will work fine!